# How to extract all attributes from img tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I was trying to use Nokogiri to turn:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="img/logologo.png" alt="">
```

to:

```
<%= image_tag('img/logologo.png', :class => 'img-responsive', :alt => '') %>
```

Here is my code:

```
# a = <img class="img-responsive" src="img/logologo.png" alt="" width="256" height="256"> 
page = Nokogiri::HTML(a)
img = page.css('img')[0]
src =  ""
alt =  ""
class_atr = ""
src =  img['src'] if img['src'].present?
alt =  img['alt'] if img['alt'].present?
class_atr = img['class'] if img['class'].present?
result = "<%= image_tag(\'" + src + '\', :class => \'' + class_atr + '\', :alt => \'' + alt + '\')%>'
```

This is kind of like hard code, is there a way I can extract all attributes and its src?

The image tag might contain `height` or `width` parameters. How do I extract all attributes automatically and make them into ERB?

Comment: Why do you want to translate a static `img` html tag into an `image_tag` with hardcodes attributes? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: When I was developing `erb` page, I need to convert `<img src="img/logologo.png">` due to rails assets pipeline. My front-end partner only know how to write `html` instead of `erb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code to iterate over all `<img>` tags inside the HTML markup and get their attributes:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML <<-html
    <img class="img-responsive1" src="img/logologo.png" alt="" width="256" height="256">
    <a href="#">A tag</a>
    <img class="img-responsive2" src="logologo222.png">
html

page.css('img').each do |img_node|
    img_attributes = img_node.attributes.values # list of image attributes

    # e.g., to output key-value pairs:
    img_attributes.each do |attr|
        p [attr.name, attr.value]
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, there are lots of things to work on. Let's start with how you're parsing the HTML. If all you're doing is parsing a snippet or single tag, you can use DocumentFragment to tell Nokogiri to not add the usual HTML tags:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<img class="img-responsive" src="img/logologo.png" alt="">')
doc.to_html # => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body><img class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"img/logologo.png\" alt=\"\"></body></html>\n"
```

Instead, you can do:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse('<img class="img-responsive" src="img/logologo.png" alt="">')
doc.to_html # => "<img class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"img/logologo.png\" alt=\"\">"
```

Next, don't use `css`, `xpath` or `search` when you mean `at`, `at_css` or `at_xpath`. Meditate on this:

```
doc.css('img').class # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
doc.at('img').class # => Nokogiri::XML::Element

doc.css('img')[0].to_html # => "<img class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"img/logologo.png\" alt=\"\">"
doc.css('img').first.to_html # => "<img class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"img/logologo.png\" alt=\"\">"
doc.at('img').to_html # => "<img class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"img/logologo.png\" alt=\"\">"
```

That `css`, `xpath` and `search` return a NodeSet is significant and something to remember. `at` and its variants are equivalent to using `first` or `[0]` on the returned NodeSet, returning the first node, so use `at` and friends if that's what you mean as it results in code that's not as noisy.

Here's how I'd go about it:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse('<img class="img-responsive" src="img/logologo.png" alt="">')

img = doc.at('img')
img_src = img.delete('src')
img_params = img.map { |p, v| ":%s => '%s'" % [p, v] }.join(', ') 
# => ":class => 'img-responsive', :alt => ''"

img_template = "<%%= image_tag('%s', %s) %%>" % [img_src, img_params]  
# => "<%= image_tag('img/logologo.png', :class => 'img-responsive', :alt => '') %>"
```

Of course, using `:k => "v"` format for key/values is old-school. I'd recommend changing to:

```
img_params = img.map { |p, v| "%s: '%s'" % [p, v] }.join(', ') # => "class: 'img-responsive', alt: ''"
```

which results in:

```
"<%= image_tag('img/logologo.png', class: 'img-responsive', alt: '') %>"
```